# (In Tcl) Is there a good way to operate the foreach statement only at the 'first' and 'last'?

Tags: tcl

I made this code.

```
set b {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}
set start 0
foreach a $b {
    if {$start==0} {
        puts "first sentence : $a" 
    } elseif { [llength $b] == $start+1} {
        puts "last sentence : $a"
    } else {
        puts $a
    }
    incr start
}
```

I'm currently using the "if, elseif, and else in the foreach statement", it feels very inefficient.

Is there any good way to detect the beginning and the end?

Comment: Your example code doesn't include any `if` statement or any `foreach` statement.  It's not clear exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Do you need to inspect all the elements of the list? Would using `lindex $list 0` and `lindex $list end` help? You can get the number of items in the list with `llength $list`